# How can i find x64 libs for Skobbler library?

Tags: android, libraries, skmaps, skobbler-maps

We use old version of Scobbler in our project, and now we can't publish our updated apk because of new Google Play 64-bit requirement:

https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2019/01/get-your-apps-ready-for-64-bit.html

There are on only x32 lib files in our project, we have't necessary x64.

We bought it and we use it legal, but Scobbler closed their sources about year ago. So now we can't just download files from their site or git(as patchnotes says, Scobbler releaze library for x64 on last patches).

So, what should we do? Is there any way to find files for x64 support? Scobbler is very important for us, we can't replace it(we tried).

We write to their support several days ago, but no one response. As i think, no one will.

Comment: not sure i understand you correct. i talk to:

https://www.skobbler.com/

Comment: Better ask the author of the library for the architecture support. They can help you with it

Comment: i tried to find him, but i failed. All i have is support email and their git, git give me nothing.

Answer (score 0):

Check this [link](https://developer.skobbler.com/changelog/android/3.2.0)
Here you can see the change logs for the SDK

**Android SDK change log from version 3.1.0 to version 3.2.0**

> New features

*64 bit architecture for SDK*

By using this version most of your methods might get changed.

An alterantive patch is to use this in build.gradle

```
android {
defaultConfig {
    ndk {
        abiFilters "armeabi", "armeabi-v7a", "x86"
    }
  }
}
```

Also add `android.useDeprecatedNdk=true` into gradle.properties

Finally create a new folder named `armeabi` under the `libs` and copy 32bit .so file into that folder.

Comment: Yes, i know it. Our version is lower, and we can't update it to 3.2.0 because authors closed their sources. We connect this library "by hands", without any remote repositories, so i have not way to update lib with it.

Comment: it should not matter that they "closed their sources". Follow https://developer.skobbler.com/getting-started/android#sec001

Comment: Ya, we tryed `defaultConfig`. We failed, because, if i understand it clear, we have't nesserary file for "arm64-v8a" folder. We have `.so` files in `armeabi`, `armeabi-v7a` and `x86`. That is why we can't follow this instruction, we can't complete first step =)

Comment: remove from abiFilters? Ya, we tried it, Google don't pass our update because of requirement. So, we don't even have folder with it.

Comment: did you try removing `mip` from adbFilters? what's the current status. If it's a warning you can ignore that @KirstenLy

Answer (score 0):

Please check the Android SDK Public Release Change log from 3.2.0 to 3.3.0: https://developer.skobbler.com/changelog/android/3.3.0

Send mail to customer support if needed.